# (Framed) environment blank spaces

Tags: macros, environments, white-space

Could be a very beginner question, but still. Considering the following:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
...
\newcommand{\some}{\textcolor{red}{\lstinline{some}}}
\newcommand{\other}{\textcolor{blue}{\lstinline{other}}}
...
\begin{document}
....
\begin{framed}
  \some \other
\end{framed}
....
\end{document}
```

Which goes into this:[image]

Why is there no white space between `some` and `other`, when there is a blank space there in the source? How would it be possible to make it consider the blank space in the output?

Comment: Because TeX gobbles white space after commands. Use `\some\ \other`, for example to insert an explicit space character

Comment: You could use the `xspace` package as well. And well be punished by some certain Italian Professor for using it. I will be punished for suggesting it ;-)

Comment: Thanks! What about passing some math as argument to a new command? Considering this `\newcommand{\evenmore}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\lstinline{#1}}}` with `\evenmore{$\sim$}`?